Stability of $y''+ay'+by=0$
I have a question regarding the stability of the ODE $y''+ay'+by=0$. By letting $x = y'$, we get the system:
\begin{align*}
& \frac{dy}{dt} = x \\
& \frac{dx}{dt} = -ax-by
\end{align*}
Or
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{dy}{dt} \\
\frac{dx}{dt}
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
-a & -b
\end{bmatrix}
}_{=:A}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
By calculating the eigenvalues of A at $(0,0)$, I get the polynomial:
\begin{align*}
p_A({\lambda}) = \lambda^2+(b-1)\lambda - b = 0
\end{align*}
Which gives $\lambda=1$ and $\lambda = -b$. Because $(0,0)$ is isolated (?), would this imply that the point cannot be stable because $Re(1)>0$? By looking at the solutions of different values for $a,b$, I get that $a,b>0$ gives stability. Where is the issue or is it just something that I just don't understand? Im thinking that the issue is with $A$, and that it would have to be
\begin{align*}
A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -b & -a \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
But I don't understand why it makes a difference (This version of A gives $p_A(\lambda)$ as the characteristic polynomial for the ODE).

Surely the characteristic equation is $\lambda^2 + \lambda b + a$? (See controllable canonical form.) Damping has a huge effect on stability.

Oops, I managed to transpose the $a,b$.

You're mixing up the order of $x$ and $y$ in your matrix equation. Be consistent!

In order to solve your ODE just to have a comfortable notation (at least for me...), we want to solve
$$\ddot y+a\dot y+by = 0 $$
then we put $x =\dot y$ and we have
$$\begin{cases}
\dot x = -ax-by\\
\dot y = x\\
\end{cases}$$
the matrix associated to this linear system is (note that I think you made small mistake on your system...)
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
-a &-b \\
1& 0\end{pmatrix}$$
we work out the eigenvalues of $A$:
$$(a+\lambda)\lambda +b = 0 \\
\lambda ^2 +a\lambda + b = 0\\
\lambda_\pm = \frac{-a \pm\sqrt{a^2-4b} }{2} $$
from here there's a multitude of possibilities for stability.

Note that we are studying something with the form of
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\dot x \\
\dot y
\end{pmatrix} = A \begin{pmatrix}
 x \\
y
\end{pmatrix} $$
if you change the order on LHS you have to do as well RHS
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\dot y \\
\dot x
\end{pmatrix} = A' \begin{pmatrix}
 y \\
x
\end{pmatrix} $$
or you will experiment that with a change of rows you change the nature of the stability and well this should not happen...

Hope this helps!
